# How to vertical align bottom

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML and CSS:

HTML

```
<div class="eq">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bar {
    background-color: green;
    width:15px;
    height:40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    bottom:0;
}

.eq {
    min-height:50px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

I want to vertically-align:bottom the green bars inside the blue div, however it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qRH33/

Comment: Here is a helpful read on `position`ed elements, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290943/css-relative-right-or-bottom-almost-never-work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally though that changing `.bar` to `display:table-cell`, would work, [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/qRH33/3/) however, in doing that, the cell takes the same height as the parent element.

The only solution that comes to mind is wrapping the span elements:

```
<div class="eq">
    <div id="bars">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    ...
    <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then using the following CSS [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/y58B5/1/) - it works.

```
.bar {
    background-color: green;
    width:15px;
    height:40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
#bars {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.eq {
    min-height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:table;
}
```

Basically, we assign `display:table-cell`, and `vertical-align:bottom` to the wrapping element, `#bars`. This works for varying heights. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/y58B5/)

Note, that the spacing between the `.bar` elements is because of the fact that they are `inline-block` elements. If you want to prevent that, see this [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/y58B5/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Just give a `line-height` to your `div` container, which is equal to the `div`'s height.

```
line-height: 50px;
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qRH33/2/).

Comment: This way would work but if you look at his `CSS` it has `min-height: 50px`. If the height gets any larger it will not change the `line-height`. I had `min-width` in my previous comment, sorry about that.