# How do I get this select to vertically align to the bottom?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have this simple code:

```
<div>
  <select style="float:right; vertical-align:bottom;">
    <option>Status</option>
  </select>
  <h3 style"font-size: 72px;">header</h3>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pqLmtskd/1

It seems like a no-brainer, but I'm missing something fundamental...

Can you please show me how to get the select element to go down to the bottom of the h3 tag? Also, if you can help me understand why it won't do that with my code, that would be helpful.

I've read this question here:
[How to vertical align bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937527/how-to-vertical-align-bottom)

But to have to use so much code just to get an element to move downwards compared to its neighbor seems a bit lengthy. It seems like the concept of 
    vertical-align:bottom
should be self-explanatory.

Please see the image below. I would like the select on the right to line up with the lowest edge of the green text.

[image: picture 1]

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>
  <h3 style"font-size: 72px;">header</h3>
  <select>
    <option>Status</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

You need to put the h3 tag before the select in order to get it the way you want

Comment: Do like this, just add the float: right to the parent div

`<div style="float: right">
  <h3 style"font-size: 72px;">header</h3>
  <select>
    <option>Status</option>
  </select>
</div>
`

Comment: a great css tool for doing layouts is flexbox check this link it will help you a lot `https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you want your drop-menu to be on top your H3 tag so this would look like that:

```html
    <div style='position:relative;'>
      <select style="bottom:0;right:0;">
        <option>Status</option>
      </select>
      <h3 style"font-size: 72px;">header</h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, please notice the select should float right. I will edit my question with an image for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the picture correctly, you would like the select menu to sit to the right, just above the top part of the header. If that is the case, you could use flexbox to stack the select and header and then float the menu to the right.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

select {
  float:right; 
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <select>
      <option>Status</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <h3>header</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like, please, for the select on the right to go down, so that the bottom edge of the select will be flush with the bottom edge of the header.