# Sliding a Div using 'right' css and touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am developing a webapp and need to use touchevents to 'slide' a number of divs and reveal another item underneath one. These divs are floated either left or right and must only be able to be dragged about 60px from their starting point and back again.

```
#container{
  height: 200px;
}

#left{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  left: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

#right{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  right: 10px;
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
}
```

So far I have managed to tweak some existing code to get the left divs moving correctly by modifying the 'left' css on a swipe.

However I can't seem to get the code working for using the 'right' css for the right-hand divs.

I've created an example codepen [here](http://codepen.io/RBrNx/pen/pRayvK), how can I get the existing code to move the left div via the 'left' css AND the right div via the 'right' css?

PLEASE NOTE: The codepen above will only function via a Touch Device or by using the Touch Device tools present in Chrome (perhaps other browsers too)

Comment: can you please give me full code with wireframe ? so that I can understand problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `relative` positioning you need to use `left` and `top`, so instead do:

```
left: -10px;
```

While `right` and `bottom` work with relative positioning, [it may not work in the way you are expecting it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290943/css-relative-right-or-bottom-almost-never-work).

Comment: Thanks Spencer, rewrote my Codepen and got it working!